# error when run bundle install -without production on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, bundle

im currently trying to run bundle install -without production on Ubuntu 12.10

this is what i get

> oyebimbola@ubuntu:~/rails_projects/first_app$ bundle install --without production
>   :1:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb (LoadError)
>       from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in`'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating rubygems with following command:

```
gem update --system
```

After that install the latest version of bundler

```
gem update bundler
```